# Finite groups of non zero real number under binary operation multiplication

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups

How we can show that {1} and {1,-1} are the only finite groups of nonzero real numbers under binary operations multiplication?

Comment: The only torsion elements (equivalently, roots of unity) in ${\bf R}^\times$ are $\pm1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $|a|\ne 1$, $a\ne 0$. Show that if $m\ne n$, then $a^m \ne a^n$.